# Model looks differently on one leg, has holes

Tags: 3d-models, diy-3d-printer, blender

I am currently trying to let someone print a 3D-model of mine for school. The model was made in blender.

Everything works fine until the guy imports my model via `.stl` for printing.

Suddenly the model has got holes on its left leg. What is wrong? I can not find a solution.

[image]

Comment: There is a problem, with your `stl` file, it most probably has some inverted normals. This is quite a common problem with Blender generated files, look into this [topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/15868/).

Comment: Hopefully, Trish's link specific to Blender will fix the problem. In general drawings have issues when surfaces have the inner and outer sides of the surface assigned in reverse. Extra surfaces inside the solid can also cause a problem. These surfaces need to be deleted.

Comment: There is also a dedicated Blender SE site at https://blender.stackexchange.com/  that may be worth searching.